# Using json to post data from tinyMCE to Web API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, tinymce

I have a Span that I have attached TinyMCE to so that I can do inline editing. When I make changes I want to post the changed content back to my Web API call as a json object.

Using X-Editable I was able to do this but I am trying to get away from WYSIHTML5. 
This is my Jquery code to init TinyMCE and attach a function to the Save event.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        tinyMCE.init({
            selector: ".editable",
            inline: true,
            plugins: "preview autoresize save",
            toolbar1: 'preview | save',
            menubar: "edit insert | tools",
            autoresize_min_height: 100,
            resize: 'both',
            statusbar: true,
            save_enablehendirty: true,
            setup: function (editor) {
                editor.on('SaveContent', function () {
                   MySaveFunction;
                });
            },
            menu: {
                edit: { title: 'Edit', items: 'undo redo | cut copy paste pastetext | selectall ' },
                tools: { title: 'Tools', items: 'spellchecker code' }
            }
        });
```

One of the issues I'm running into is that the SaveContent tries to post the whole page and all I really want to do is post the contents of the active editor that I am using.

Does anyone know of a good example on how to post from a save in a specific TinyMCE edit area?